# Object not removed physically JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cdi

I'm trying to remove a object using EntityManager, everything works fine without error but when i do some query in database the object return, not deleted in database.

My EntityManager inject:

```
public class CdiApplicationConfig {

    @Inject
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("generalPU");
        return emf;
    }

    public void close(@Disposes EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        emf.close();
    }

    @Produces
    @TransactionAttribute // is a bit better than @RequestScoped because it won't allow perform injection outside transaction context
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void close(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

See my remove action:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void delete(Bean bean) {
    try {
        bean = entityManager.merge(bean);
        entityManager.remove(bean);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new DAOException("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar deletar");
    }
    }
```

As i said, there is not error but BEAN is not deleted physically. I'm using JPA/Hibernate + CDI.

**Edit 1:**

I solved the problem making Application-Managed Transaction like this:

```
begin();
        bean = entityManager.merge(bean);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.refresh(bean);
        commit();
```

Where begin() and commit() use EntityManager.getTransaction()

Comment: The code attempting to remove an entity is not in a transaction context which it is supposed to be in to perform a delete operation.

Comment: You are obtaining `EntityManager` from `EntityManagerFactory` in which case you are not using a container managed `EntityManager` and `@TransactionAttribute` is simply ignored. Use a container managed `EntityManager`. If it is not an option for some reasons, then you will have to begin and commit transactions manually (using `UserTransaction` or whatever) or use `javax.transaction.Transactional` to make CDI managed beans transactional.

Comment: I m using EJB as a container-managed , i leave Spring to use CDI. I cant understand why TrasactionAttribute is ignored.

Comment: In fact, i discover the problem but i dont know how fix. My application just havE CDI annotations and EJB dont understand this beans. How can i mix EJB and CDI to use Transacional ?

Comment: If you are really using EJBs (you are mixing things like Spring and EJBs which I do not understand. One should use either of them), then the code you wrote is not required at all. Just use the `@PersistenceContext` annotation to inject a container managed `EntityManager` in EJBs. Always insisting upon using the `@Inject` annotation to inject a container managed `EntityManager` in EJBs is a major misunderstanding (It is not required at all for a container managed `EntityManager`).

Comment: ... It is however very useful, when you do not have a chance to use a container managed `EntityManager` and you have to obtain `EntityManager` manually (Thus, things like EJBs are not part of your application).

Comment: I'm not using Spring, so i cant use @PersistenceContext

Comment: As per your comment, "*I m using EJB as a container-managed*". If it is really the case, then nothing can prevent you from using `@PersistenceContext`.

Comment: I solved the issue with Application Managed Transcation, i edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is like below to handle the transaction manually...
However if you use spring you can configure the transaction so you need not have to handle the transaciton in every method

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void delete(Bean bean) {
    try {
        bean = entityManager.merge(bean);

        EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        entityManager.remove(bean);

        tx.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new DAOException("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar deletar");
    }
    }
```

Comment: The approach will fail with an exception, if this code is written in an EJB (as implied by `@TransactionAttribute`) which uses container managed global (distributed) JTA transactions and dislikes resource-specific local transactions (EJBs do not allow resource-specific local transactions. Unlike `UserTransaction`, `EntityManager#getTransaction()` retrieves a resource local transaction which is not permitted in EJBs as they use JTA).